# Trouble installing Matlab due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, matlab

So whenever I try to install Matlab, the first image appears, but then goes away and that's the end of it.  Here's what I'm doing-

```
user@host$> cd ~/mathworks_downloads
user@host$> unzip matlab_R2012a_student_glnx86_installer.zip
user@host$> ./install
```

The Matlab logo and image pop up here for a few seconds before going away.  This is the output I receive-

```
Could not find JRE for glnxa64.  Trying glnx86.
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Component
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at $Proxy11.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructionContext.createProxy(ConstructionContext.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:758)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:754)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:758)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:754)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:758)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:804)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:754)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:793)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.WizardLauncher.startWizard(WizardLauncher.java:160)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.WizardLauncher.start(WizardLauncher.java:75)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.AbstractLauncher.launch(AbstractLauncher.java:27)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.AbstractLauncher.launchStandalone(AbstractLauncher.java:18)
    at com.mathworks.studentinstaller.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:23)
Finished
```

After that, nothing happens, although apparently a Matlab window is supposed to open.  Is this a problem caused by the fact that I'm running OpenJKD 7 instead of JRE 7u7?

Comment: It means you did not install all of the required dependencies. This includes some pointers: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/316025

Answer (score 1):

Try the official Oracle Java, or there's usually a JVM bundled with the installation disc.

You can get Oracle Java from http://www.Java.com (I don't believe it's in the partner repos any more [citation needed]).

The old Sun JVM comes bundled with the installer, and the script is trying to use it, but you could try installing it separately.  I'd give you more instructions, but would just be guessing: probably copy it into `/opt`?